# curl: The URI prefix is not recognized

Tags: docker, containers, port

When i want to check my ports it allows only my 80th port. I also tried with http://. It was the same. I can't check specific port. Check the screenshot. My Operation System is Windows 10 Pro and this is Powershell. I also checked it on CMD too. I'm sharing the both code and image which includes my code.

:

```
curl localhost  /* ( It shows the information as in image, there is no problem with default port 80) */

curl localhost: 8080  //(httpd's port as i assigned)
curl: The URI prefix is not recognized.

curl localhost: 3306 // (mysql's port as i assigned)
curl: The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wuFF.png)

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Also, you are not giving curl a URL type prefix (like `http://`), to tell it which protocol to use.

Comment: Hello Amitai, there are many codes so i added just part of codes. I tried with http:// it doesn't work too.

Comment: Edit you question to reflect what you tried. You cannot get answers related to questions you do not ask. Also, the space between the host name and the port number should be removed: `curl http://localhost:8080`

Comment: That's what i love this site! Thanks a lot Amitai! It worked with that way. Best regards.

Answer (score 6):

The correct invocation of `curl` needs to include a protocol identifier in the URL, and the port needs to be attached to the host name with a colon and no space. For example, to access an HTTP server on the local host, serving through port 8080, you need to use:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 4):

On Windows use curl.exe localhost:8080

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues with type nodeport in minikube and you have Windows OS

use these two commands

```
minikube service list

curl.exe http://URL_SECTION_IP:EXPOSED nodeport
```